# Copying decimal values from Excel to C# causes to copy only displayed values

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I'm trying to copy some values from excel spreadsheet into C# WPF app. I noticed that when I select cells in Excel and copy them into clipboard then when pasting it into WPF app I get displayed value not the real value i.e consider cell with value 2.232323. If in Excel in "Format Cells" window I set only one decimal place then excel will display 2.2. If now I copy it into WPF then I get 2.2 instead of 2.232323. I noticed that Notepad does the same thing. Is there a way to get a real value? Code which I am using to copy cells:

```
DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()), Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: change `DataFormats.Text` to `DataFormats.Value`

Comment: Value doesn't exist in DataFormats class. I tried CommaSeparatedValue but it gives displayed values as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
IDataObject dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = dataObject.GetData("XML Spreadsheet") as System.IO.MemoryStream;
if(stream != null)
{
    stream.SetLength(stream.Length - 1);
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(stream);
    XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";

    double actualValue;
    var data = xml.Descendants(ns + "Data").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute(ns + "Type") == "Number");
    if(data != null && data.Any())
    {
        actualValue = (double)data.First();
        MessageBox.Show(actualValue.ToString());
    }

    stream.Dispose();
}
```