# copy data from Excel cells without formatting c#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, copy-paste

I have winform project in c# that I want to copy data from Excel cells to my datagirdview. But the excell cells is formatted with 2 digits after the comma.I want to get all value.

What i mean :

The excell cell value = 884,79258

Formatted value = 884,79

I am getting the data with `Clipboard.GetText()` method. Bu it gives me formatted value(884,79).

But i want the get all value which is 884,79258.

These are my codes

```
String[] lines = Clipboard.GetText().Split('\n');
string result = lines[0];
```

[image]

Thanx.

**Edit:**

Thanx to dr.nulll. The link that he shared is worked.

I am sharing the link below for those who have similar request.

[Copying decimal values from Excel to C# causes to copy only displayed values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481912/copying-decimal-values-from-excel-to-c-sharp-causes-to-copy-only-displayed-value/42484531#42484531)

Comment: You need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484531/14171304).

Answer (score 1):

Don’t go via the clipboard. Either use Excel via interop or a 3rd party library like NPOI. If you must use the clipboard then the value copied reflects the current formatting of the cell, so you need it set to show 4 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Hımm. But the user will copy data from excel sheet and will paste to my app. Actually i tried to copy data from excel and paste to word document. The result is same. THe reason of that the clipboard as you said.